# I'm trying to link other components as options in my dropdowns react-router-dom issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, dropdown, react-router-dom

[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRAkS.jpg)> Hi all I'm trying to use optionsBar & optionsPie as dropdown options in my header-list item, just like how I'm using other links for **home** and **aboutUs**

Hi all I'm trying to use optionsBar & optionsPie as dropdown options in my header-list item, just like how I'm using other links for **home** and **aboutUs**

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react'
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
    import { Dropdown, Menu, Icon} from `semantic-ui-react`;


    const optionsBar = [
      {as: Link, content: 'Rank ', to: '/barT', key: 'Rank'},
      {as: Link, content: 'Category', to: '/barK', key: 'Category'},
    ]

    const optionsPie = [
      {as: Link, content: 'Rank ', to: '/pieT', key: 'Rank'},
      {as: Link, content: 'Category', to: '/pieK', key: 'Category'},
    ]



      class Header extends Component{

          render(){
            return (
           <header>
              <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <div className="navbar-header">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">Relation document </a>
              </div>
              <ul className="nav navbar-nav "> 
              <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
              <li><Link to='/page1'>ABout Us</Link></li>
              <li><Link to='/page2'>Info</Link></li>

              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav dropdown">
                  <Dropdown  header=`Select Rank or Category` options={optionsBar} defaultValue={optionsBar[0].value}  text='Bar' />  
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav dropdown">
                  <Dropdown  header='Select Rank or Category' options={optionsPie} defaultValue={optionsPie[0].value}  text='Pie' />  
                </a>
              </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
              </nav>
            </header>

            )
          }
    }

    export default Header
```

Comment: can you please share some information on what you are trying to achieve and what exactly is the issue so that we can help :)

Comment: I'm trying to create a dropdown as a line item in my header. The options in the dropdown will link to someother pages in this case it is to  "/BarK" and  "/barT"

Comment: Edited but still getting a error: Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`error: Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>`

You are getting this error because you have two `<a>` tags nested in each other, e.g.

`<a><a>...</a></a>`

I believe it is happening here:

```
<a class="nav dropdown">
  <Dropdown options={optionsBar} .../>  
</a>
```

The `Dropdown` items are rendered as `Link` components (see `optionsBar`), and because `Link` ultimately becomes an `<a>` tag, you get nested `<a>` tags.

Comment: You can try replacing `<a class="...">` with `<div class="...">`.   The warning should go away, but it might break your styling.

Comment: yes CSS is messed up. Thanks for the suggestion it works :)